# How to read data from ElasticSearch in pyspark (facing java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)?

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark

I have a question.
I read data from Elastic Search.

The data schema has nested array.

```
df = spark.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").option("es.query",dsl).option("es.read.field.as.include",column_list).load(es_index) 

ex) 
root
 |-- aaa: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bbb: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ddd: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- eee: string (nullable = true)
```

When I save or show(), I see error message.

- java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

What is the reason?
Please help me.

Comment: df = spark.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").option("es.query",dsl).option("es.read.field.as.include",column_list).load(es_index)

Comment: you could `edit` your question to add more information if needed. It's not recommended to add details in `comment` when no one answered your question yet.

Comment: @AmirMaleki Okay, thank you.